NextJS spams 'TypeError: result.pipeToNodeResponse is not a function' in error log
I have a NextJS site running in an Azure Web App. It spams this error message to the terminal every 3 seconds or so:
TypeError: result.pipeToNodeResponse is not a function
    at Object.sendRenderResult (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/send-payload.js:118:18)
    at NextNodeServer.sendRenderResult (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:368:34)
    at NextNodeServer.pipe (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:380:25)
    at async Object.fn (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:727:21)
    at async Router.execute (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:247:36)
    at async NextNodeServer.run (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:346:29)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleRequest (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:284:20)

I tried looking through the NextJS source code but wasn't able to track down a cause for this issue. The site itself returns a 500 if you try to visit it.
Info:
Node: 18 LTS
Next: 12.3.0

What might cause such an error?

icanfathom If possible, share your GitHub repository?

Are you using cacheHandler?

I'm not intentionally calling cacheHandler. It's possible there's one by default? This error shows up on any request and prevents NextJS from serving anything, including a 404 page.
